# Prettyfaces: Set a bean property to some constant value, on observing a specific url pattern

Tags: java, jsf, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

While writing the URL mapping rules for Prettyfaces in `pretty-config.xml` I would like to add a rule that whenever a particular pattern is observed in URL then set a specific constant value to bean property.
For e.g. when there is a pattern like `../products/electronics`  then it should set bean property `bean.category` to `ELECTRONICS_ITEMS`. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use a path parameter and convert the value from the URL to your constant in a page action method. Something like this:

```
<url-mapping id="products"> 
  <pattern value="/products/#{bean.category}/" /> 
  <view-id value="/faces/shop/store.jsf" />
  <action>#{bean.action}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

And the action method:

```
public void action() {

  if( "electronics".equals(this.category) ) {
    this.category = "ELECTRONICS_ITEMS";
  }
  // more categories...

}
```

Comment: That's the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

as i am using prettyfaces annotations i dont know about `pretty-config.xml` if i got this condition then i will use it in annotations like this

```
 @URLAction(mappingId = "someMappingId", onPostback = false)
 public String setConstantValue() {

// set your bean here
return null;

}
```