# With a specific URL pattern set bean property to a specific constant value

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

With **Prettyfaces** in my **JSF 2.1** application, I want like to add a rule that whenever a particular URL  pattern is seen, then set a specific constant value to bean property. For e.g. when there is a pattern like `../products/electronics` then it should set bean property `bean.category` to `"ELECTRONICS_ITEMS"`.

**How could I do that ?**

Comment: i have post answer on this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470974/prettyfaces-set-a-bean-property-to-some-constant-value-on-observing-a-specific]

Comment: What's the difference between this question and the one @mohsinazeem refers to?